# Insignificant variable in Error Correction Model

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, inference, ecm

While working with ECM model short-term and long-term models, I have identified certain variables that appear to be statistically insignificant (P value > 0.05). Is it acceptable to have some variables show insignificance within the Error Correction Model (ECM)?

If it is ok then what will be my forecasted equation

Y = B + significant variable + insignificant variable
or
Y = B + significant variable

Answer (score 0):

For a statistical model to be adequate, there is no (strict) requirement that all the estimated coefficients must be statistically significant. Thus you may keep your model as is. Depending on the intended use of the model, you also choose to remove the insignificant term. E.g. if your intention is to use the model for forecasting, then one rule of thumb is to keep the variable if it is significant at 15.7% level. This cutoff corresponds to the model's AIC value being lower (that is, better) than the AIC value of the model without the term. Why this rule of thumb? Roughly speaking, a model with a lower AIC value should do better at forecasting.